# MVC 4 Razor Jquery Ajax returns JSON.parse() syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I have an MVC 4 application login page in which I am trying to use a jquery ajax request to my login controller to see whether the user exists or not. My jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

            var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("Index", "Auth")';
            var username = $("#UserName").val();
            var password = $("#Password").val();
            var jsonString = '[{"username": "' + username + '", "password": "' + password + '"}]';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: actionUrl,
                data: jsonString,
                success: function (data) {                        
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {                    
                    alert(xhr.status + " - " + thrownError);
                    alert(ajaxOptions);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
```

My index controller on my auth action:

```
// POST: /login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public JsonResult Index(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {                
            return this.Json(String.Empty);                          
        }
```

My route configuration:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AuthRoot",
                url: "login",
                defaults: new { controller = "Auth", action = "Index", returnUrl = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AuthRoot2",
                url: "login/{username}/{password}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Auth", action = "Index", returnUrl = UrlParameter.Optional, username = UrlParameter.Optional, password = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I'm not sure what is happening here because every time I generate the ajax request, the on error bit runs. Here's the response header from firebug:

```
Response Headers
Cache-Control   private
Connection  Close
Content-Length  3835
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Tue, 11 Feb 2014 01:51:34 GMT
Server  ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version 4.0

Request Headers
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8;
Cookie  __RequestVerificationToken=GqfLsAL26Vo4UM6PiXwON-zGO8M4Y9v1WBA4XQ8tuxDtvPiW7aQy5JKIP85ULQawEoPeB2F0XDSsxd0jsl8braOxMEAkXR1V1LAgdmxBe5iQDy_1qOfX-fjPpebgHgM2Qyq8kv1pa-y4cjfmYhSthw2
Host    localhost:50925
Referer http://localhost:50925/login
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

And this is what I post:

```
JSON            

0
    Object { username="manager", password="P@ssw0rd"}

password
    "P@ssw0rd"

username
    "manager"
Source
[{"username": "manager", "password": "P@ssw0rd"}]
```

When I put a breakpoint on the controller and debug, it never fires, and instead I receive a json.parse syntax error. I can't seem to figure out why. I have tried so many of the other solutions on this and other websites but they don't seem to do the trick for me. I must be missing something.

Comment: Does the console give any errors? I copy pasted your code and it works for me. Weird.

Comment: Console doesn't give any errors, no.

Answer (score 0):

you should change your Action method :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Index(LoginModel model)
    {                
        return this.Json(String.Empty);                          
    }

   or if above not work then use following:
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Index(string username,string password)
    {                
        return this.Json(String.Empty);                          
    }
```

Comment: yeah so neither of your suggestions worked. I still got 200 syntax error invalid character. parserror